# Does globally stability implies existence of Lyapunov function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, soft-question, reference-works

I recently had a chance to ask a professor this question and he mentioned that this is true for ordinary differential equations (but not for delay differential equation). He did not remember the reference, I could not find a reference for this, so can anyone please point me to the right source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find what you need in this paper and the references of  **Karafyllis**:

*Converse Lyapunov–Krasovskii theorems for systems described by neutral functional differential equations in Hale's form*

Pierdomenico Pepe  & Iasson **Karafyllis**